# Issue in accessing a supposedly disabled function in CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I realized a very significant problem in my application. It's about hire function.What happens is even an applicant has already been hired, if the client clicks the reject button on the proposals page, the status changes from "Approved" to rejected.

I think I should change something in this part:

```
public function approve_job_proposal($job_id, $provider_id, $proposal_id) 
{
    //updates job status to "Closed" when a proposal is already accepted/approved
    $data = array
    (
        'provider_id' => $provider_id,
        'status' => "Awarded"
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $job_id);
    $this->db->update('job', $data);

    $data = array
    (
        'status' => "Approved"
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $proposal_id);
    $this->db->update('job_proposal', $data);

}

public function reject_job_proposal($job_id, $provider_id, $proposal_id) 
{
    //updates provider's job proposal to "Rejected"
    $data = array
    (
        'status' => "Rejected"
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $proposal_id);
    $this->db->update('job_proposal', $data);

}
```

How do I disable any button if the client has already hired such provider?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question is, how do I disable any button once the client has already hired a particular provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your database to ensure the proposal has not already been accepted with something along these lines. If you want to do it for both instances (accept, and reject), perhaps you could move the check into an additional function that checks to see if a proposal is already in an 'ending' state (i.e. Accepted or Rejected).

A sample addition to your `reject_job_proposal` method could be...

```
public function reject_job_proposal ($job_id, $provider_id, $proposal_id) 
{
    $this->db->select('status');
    $this->db->from('job_proposal');
    $this->db->where('id', $proposal_id);
    $query  = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->row();
    if ($result->status === 'Accepted') {
        // Throw error message, e.g. 'Sorry, this job has been accepted!'
        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, sir Jonnu!! However, I got an error: Message: Undefined variable: result  I will try to solve..

Comment: Apologies, I left a typo in the code. Please try the updated version.

Comment: It seems there was a === and result ->result

Comment: It was the second... [=== is definitely a valid comparison operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)!

Comment: Oh yes, although == also worked. Thanks so much for your help!! God bless! ;)